# How do I interpret changing to report to my previous manager's manager

Tags: manager, promotion

During a meeting with my manager that I get along with, how do / should I interpret soon reporting to my n+2 (manager's manager)? There was no mention of a title change or salary increase but increased visibility to business stakeholders is mentioned. This seems like more trust by my company on me and perhaps "training" to move upwards to more senior role?

My original manager is staying and I have been with the company for about 5 and half years. I am currently a team lead with about 8 direct reports. This takes place in the cybersecurity profession within financial services sector.

**Edit for more clarity** My evaluation last year was great,noting my technical solid skills, my initiative, and how I mentor younger colleagues well. My responsibilities within my current role does include supervisory responsibility.

I am interested in what the implications of the change in reporting structure may mean.  I am interested in staying as I am satisfied with my work, great colleagues, and am decently compensated.

Comment: what do you mean by "reporting"? are you going to have 1 meeting a month or a week?

Comment: @aaa my current n+2 will become my direct manager or n+1

Comment: Congratulations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely to be a positive thing for your career. Congrats!

Don't overthink the corporate hierarchy thing. This is 21st century business, not medieval Byzantium.

Your manager-to-be surely thinks it will be good to have you as a direct report. Only that manager knows exactly why.  You should ask directly. "What expectations do you have of members of your team? What do you expect of me? How will you know I'm doing the right things? Do you have any kind of special projects in mind for me?"

Answer (score 5):

> How do I interpret direct report to my n+2 manager

Interpret it as a positive chance to network and impress a bit further up the food chain. The outcome and reason is an unknown but obviously your manager is involved in it which usually means you're making your manager look good. But in any event networking is always a good thing.

Comment: I’d say it is pretty clear the OP is being evaluated/groomed for bigger things.

Comment: @JonCuster Maybe.  Maybe not.  Perhaps the current manager is being reassigned to a completely new project, but the OP still has to report to somebody.  That somebody is the manager's manager.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of reasons that your employer could have made this change.  Maybe your current manager is overloaded and needs to hand you off.  Maybe there is some restructuring going on and it no longer makes sense for you to report to the current manager.

The best way to find out is to ask.